# How does one configure display of custom help on eclipse plugin preferences page

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I'm making an eclipse plugin with neon.2.  This plugin has a preferences page, and it also has some eclipse help.  I want to be able to click the question mark button on the preferences dialog and have my help appear in the preferences dialog like it does for built in preferences.

After searching several tutorials about the preferences system and also the help system, I can't find an example of how to do this.  Also, searching through many eclipse documents, wiki pages and source projects like the sources for the Java Dev Tools and other prominent plugins has not turned up anything that helps.

I'm just looking for a pointer to an example of where a plugin's preferences panel shows its own help when the preferences '?' button is clicked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the preference page `createContents` method tell the help system the id of the help for the page using:

```java
@Override
protected Control createContents(final Composite parent)
{
  PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getHelpSystem().setHelp(parent, "help context id");

  ... other code
}
```

where `help context id` is a help context id you defined using the `org.eclipse.help.contexts` extension point.

Comment: Thanks for this.  Is there a way to add a context to a FieldEditor?  I can't seem to find the parent of the text field in, say, a DirectoryFieldEditor.  @greg-449

Comment: Since DirectoryFieldEditor displays a new dialog this is going to be difficult. I'm not sure how you would go about that.

Comment: I want the help if the user clicks in the text field.  So far I've subclassed DirectoryFieldEditor so it can give me the Text object.   It wires up okay, and if the field has focus when the '?' is clicked, my context is displayed.  But the focus event on the text field doesn't trigger the context.  Maybe I can just use a tooltip instead of help.